# Sort NSDictionary keys and values in array

Tags: objective-c

I have this dictionary. I want to take values and keys in different arrays and also in order which is showing in dictionary i.e. on index=0 Key=Name, index=1 key=Password, index=2 key=Address. But problem is when i print array it comes in different order means on index=0 key=Address is come instead of Name. So,how to sort this?

```
NSDictionary *dictFields=@{
             @"name":@[_tfName.text],
             @"password":@[_tfPassword.text],
             @"address":@[_tfAddress.text]
            };

NSLog(@"%@",dictFields);

keysArr=[dictFields allKeys] ;
NSLog(@"%@",keysArr);
valuesArray=[dictFields allValues];
NSLog(@"%@",valuesArray);

NSLog(@"%@",dictFields);
```

Comment: Add the code as text, not as image

Comment: And show actual input and desired output, please.

Comment: Did you read the doc of `allKeys` and `allValues`, the "Discussion" part? Dictionaries aren't sorted.

Comment: I don't see the point of this question.  I don't see the point of his or her not running a search.  Somebody else asked the same question two days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that dictionaries do not have indexes. Only arrays have an index. So the dictionary will guarantee you to respect the key/value pairs, but you have no control on how those information are stored. As a matter of fact, if you save the content to a text file, you may see the order changing each time.

If you really want to use something that feels like a numeric index in a dictionary, use a number as a key (you will have to covert it from string to number if you plan to use it in a for/next loop for sorting). Dictionaries can contain arrays, so each key can point to an array as value.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix: use a array to save your keys.

```
NSArray *keyArr = @[@"name",@"password",@"address",@"sex"];

NSArray *valueArr = @[@"nameValue",@"passwordValue",@"addressValue",@"sexValue"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valueArr forKeys:keyArr];

//your keyArr index
NSInteger index = 0;

[dict setValue:@"newNameValue" forKey:[keyArr objectAtIndex:index]];

NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

Hope that helps